# How do you make an uploading system that sends files to database and displays them on website

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am needing to make a website where people are uploading content and my website displays it automatically in a styled form(like youtube). I want these to also be stored in a database.

I have tried finding tutorials on how to make a website that automatically uploads content onto my website, but there is nothing that tells me my answer.

I haven't been able to get anything working yet

Comment: You are looking for some kind of content management system (CMS). There are plenty of CMSs on the market; do a search.

Comment: one way to do this is with a c# web application that speaks to a database (like entity framework)